# I want to change scenes when the Lives Value turns zero but my GameOver scene isn't opening and the countdown of the lives values continues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code.I use the SceneManager.LoadScene but it doesn't seem to work at all
I have try to put it every where.It is a quiz game that has 2 lives.if you answer wrong to two question I want to load a new scene called "GameOver.unity" that is placed in my Scenes folder in Assets.The Game over scene is a simple scene that says Game Over and has a play again button(that doesn't work either)

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Question[] questions;
    private static List<Question> unansweredQuestions;

    private Question currentQuestion;

    public Text Level;
    public Text Lives;
    public Text Score;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text factText;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text trueAnswerText;
    [SerializeField]
    private Text falseAnswerText;

    [SerializeField]
    private Animator animator;

    [SerializeField]
    private float timeBetweenQuestions = 1f;

    int i = 0;
    private static int scoreValue;
    private static int levelValue=3;
    private static int levelOutput;
    private static int livesValue=2;




    void Start()
    {


        if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.Count == 0)
        {
            unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Question>();
        }

        SetCurrentQuestion();

    }


    void SetCurrentQuestion()
    {
        int questionIndex = i;
        currentQuestion = unansweredQuestions[questionIndex];
        i = i + 1;


        factText.text = currentQuestion.fact;


        if (currentQuestion.isTrue)
        {
            trueAnswerText.text = "CORRECT";
            falseAnswerText.text = "WRONG";
        }
        else
        {
            trueAnswerText.text = "WRONG";
            falseAnswerText.text = "CORRECT";
        }



    }

    IEnumerator TransitionToNextQuestion ()
    {

        unansweredQuestions.Remove(currentQuestion);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenQuestions);
        levelValue++; 
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);


    }

    public void UserSelectTrue ()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("True");
        if (currentQuestion.isTrue)
        {
            Debug.Log("CORRECT!");
            scoreValue = scoreValue + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WRONG!");
            livesValue = livesValue - 1;
        }

        StartCoroutine(TransitionToNextQuestion());
    }

    public void UserSelectFalse()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("False");
        if (!currentQuestion.isTrue)
        {
            Debug.Log("CORRECT!");
            scoreValue = scoreValue + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WRONG!");
            livesValue = livesValue - 1;
        }

        StartCoroutine(TransitionToNextQuestion());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        levelOutput = levelValue / 3;
        Level.text = string.Format("Level: {0}", levelOutput);
        Lives.text = string.Format("Lives: {0}", livesValue);
        Score.text = string.Format("Score: {0}", scoreValue);
        if (livesValue == 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you put something like `Debug.Log("no lives");` above your LoadScene, does it print?

Comment: No it doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add all of your scenes to the Build Settings to be able to load it.

`File > Build Settings > Add Open Scenes`

Also, and this is just for efficiency, you should check if livesValue == 0 right after you set it, or turn it into a property and check inside the setter, instead of checking every frame.